# Performance on loading string array multiple times from Android resources

Tags: android

I have lot of string array in Android res folder, those must be used multiple times in different places of the application.

It is safe performance side to call every time:

```
getContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.resource_id);
```

Does Android use an internal optimization or must I cache arrays to avoid to load the same data multiple times from resources?

Comment: Have you measured how long it takes to load string arrays the "easy" way that you quoted?  If not, you're just speculating that it might be slow.  There are 100 other areas your app could be slow, so I'd recommend tracking down performance issues if and when they happen.  And not sooner :-)

Comment: I was hoping that someone has tried this before me, I'm too lazy ;).
However I will try this soon and add an answer with my results to help other users.